# How to do the equivalent of "grep something * -Rin" on list of tar.gz files?

Tags: grep, tar, gz

I've got a bunch of tar.gz files and I want to do a "grep something * -Rin" as I would on them if they weren't tar.gzed. I want to keep them tar.gzed as they are, but grep on them on-the-fly and find the occurrences of my grep with the prefixed file and line number.

Something like:

```
grep mytoken1 *.tar.gz -Rin
```

and get something like:

```
my1.tar.gz,dir1/file2:123:mytoken1 is in this line  
my2.tar.gz,dir2/file3:233:mytoken1 is also in this other line  
[...]
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

zgrep (or, we believe, grep with the -Z flag) will let you grep the compressed files and I think will tell you much of what you want, but this doesn't give you the filename without a bit more work looking at the header :(

Comment: http://www.nsc.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?zgrep+1 According to this zgrep is the same as grep with the -Z flag (need zlib compiled, tho), I don't have a terminal in front of me, but I would think this would work.

Comment: *blush* it's like when I found out about ls and l. I feel grown up...

Comment: +1 zgrep should work as the `tar` format contains **verbatim** copies of file content, plus some header information and padding bytes.

Comment: This doesn't show in which file in the archive the pattern was found in.

Comment: Have edited with information from comments.

Comment: @Joe All good d00d, there's a whole family of 'z' commands, z{grep,cat} are the only ones that spring to mind at the moment, but google will help you out there. :)

Answer (score 4):

Found in [Unix script to search within a .tar or .gz file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160306/unix-script-to-search-within-a-tar-or-gz-file) :

The script :

```
for file in $(tar -tzf file.tar.gz | grep '\.txt'); do 
    tar -Oxzf file.tar.gz "$file" | grep -B 3 --label="$file" -H "string-or-regex"
done
```

will respect file boundaries and report the file names. The `| grep '\.txt` part can be adapted to your needs or dropped.

(`-z` tells `tar` it is `gzip` compressed. `-t` lists the contents.  `-x` extracts.  `-O` redirects to standard output rather than the file system.  Older `tar`s may not have the `-O` or `-z` flag, and will want the flags without `-`: e.g. `tar tz file.tar.gz`)

If your grep does not support these flags, then one can use awk :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { context=3; }
{ add_buffer($0) }
/pattern/ { print_buffer() }
function add_buffer(line)
{
    buffer[NR % context]=line
}
function print_buffer()
{
    for(i = max(1, NR-context+1); i <= NR; i++) {
        print buffer[i % context]
    }
}
function max(a,b)
{
    if (a > b) { return a } else { return b }
}
```

This will not coalesce adjacent matches, unlike grep -B, and can thus repeat lines that
are within 3 lines of two different matches.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use this quick hack:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

=begin
Quick-and-dirty way to grep in *.tar.gz archives

Assumption:
    each and every file read from any of the supplied tar archives
    will fit into memory. If not, the data reading has to be rewritten
    (a proxy that reads line-by-line would have to be inserted)
=end

require 'rubygems'
gem 'minitar'
require 'zlib'
require 'archive/tar/minitar'

if ARGV.size < 2
    STDERR.puts "#{File.basename($0)} <regexp> <file>+"
    exit 1
end

regexp = Regexp.new(ARGV.shift, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

for file in ARGV
    zr = Zlib::GzipReader.new(File.open(file, 'rb'))
    Archive::Tar::Minitar::Reader.new(zr).each do |e|
        next unless e.file?
        data = e.read
        if regexp =~ data
            data.split(/\n/).each_with_index do |l, i|
                puts "#{file},#{e.full_name}:#{i+1}:#{l}" if regexp =~ l
            end
        end
    end
end
```

which is not to say I'd recommend it for bigger archives, as each file from the archive is read into memory (twice, actually).

If you want a bit more memory-efficient version, you'd either have to go with different implementation of the `e.read` loop... or, perhaps, with a different language altogether. ;)

I could make it a bit more efficient if you're really interested... but it will definitely not compare with C or other compiled languages, in terms of raw speed.

Comment: Which version of ruby should I use? $ ruby ./tar_search.rb DSM 1.tar.gz 2.tar.gz
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem minitar (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
 from ./tar_search.rb:13:in `<main>'

Comment: I developed on 1.8.7. However, the main problem is missing gem `minitar`. Rectify that from shell: `gem install minitar`; then it should work. Also, Ruby 1.9.1 works fine (after the gem installation).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be very tricky.

In fact, tar is basically a concatenation of all its includes files, with headers addition. So basically a `grep-in-tar` function could be written to deal with that and provide information on file and line number (basic grep with header reading and line number substraction). I've not heard of such a program.

The problem is with gzip. This is a compression format so you need to decompress it if you want to access the content.

```
gunzip -c files.tgz | grep-in-tar
```

would be a way to do what you want.
At the moment you can try `gunzip -c files.tgz | grep -Rin` but it will just say that the binary file matches.

Answer (score 0):

The modular approach to *nix tools means that there's no simple way to do this efficiently with grep / tar / zcat. Ideally you want to decompress the files only once, and process each tar file in a single pass. Here's my attempt at **tgz-grep**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re,sys,tarfile

exp=re.compile(sys.argv[1])
tarfiles=sys.argv[2:]

for tfile in tarfiles:
  tar=tarfile.open(tfile, mode='r|gz')
  for file in tar:
    name=file.name
    count=0
    for line in tar.extractfile(file):
      count += 1
      if exp.search(line):
        print "%s,%s:%d:%s" % (tfile, name, count, line),
```

Note: this doesn't do directory recursion (-R) or case-insensitvity (-i), or other options supported by GNU grep, but they wouldn't be tricky to add.